# Where has RoutedEventArgs.Source gone?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, routedeventargs

I've just downloaded source code of a Silverlight app and figured out happily that there seems to be only one error keeping me from compiling it:

```
private void UserControl_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  object o = e.Source;
}
```

there seems to be no Source in RoutedEventArgs despite the fact [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.source.aspx) says it's there.

Any idea where has RoutedEventArgs.Source gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't exist in Silverlight - only in the desktop framework.

If you look at the [Silverlight `RoutedEventArgs` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms589740%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) you'll see there are fewer members than for the [desktop .NET 4 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms589740%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Then how could it be intended to work? I've got a working binary version of this app (works well as a usual Silverlight browser applet) and this source code...

Comment: @Ivan: That seems odd to me, as it's clearly *not* documented to be present in Silverlight. Does the binary version *really* refer to `Source`?

Comment: I even can't understand why would it need it as it seems to be assigned to a local variable for no further use... I could build it after disabling the line but the resulting applet doesn't work - just shows white screen...

Comment: @Ivan: It sounds like there are other things wrong then, to be honest. We can't tell what from the code you've given though, obviously.

Comment: Ok then. You've answered the question, I accept it, thanks. I will try to explore the code and contact the author to get it working...